# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby as well as rails I am getting the following error while I clicked the update button

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#update
                Couldn't find Book without an ID
                Extracted source (around line #35):
                def update
                  @book = Book.find(book1_params[:id])........here it is line number 35
                  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
                    redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book

                activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:266:in `find_with_ids'
                activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:35:in `find'
                activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) lib/active_record/deprecated_finders/relation.rb:122:in `find'
                c:in `find'
                app/controllers/books_controller.rb:35:in `update'
```

**books_controller.rb**

I am getting above error in update method.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
      def list
        @books = Book.find(:all)
      end
      def show
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      end
      def new
        @book = Book.new
        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
      end
      #  private 
      def book_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:title,:price,:subject,:description)
      end
      def create
        @book = Book.new(book_params)
        if @book.save
          redirect_to :action => 'list'
        else
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
          render :action => 'new'
        end
      end
      def edit
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])
        @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
      end

      def book1_params
        params.require(:book).permit(:id)
      end

      def update
        #below is the line I am getting the error....
        @book = Book.find(book1_params)

        if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
          redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
        else
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
          render :action => 'edit'
        end
      end
      def delete
        Book.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to :action => 'list'
      end
      def show_subjects
        @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
      end
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
LibrarayWebApplication::Application.routes.draw do

    get 'books/list'
    get 'books/new'
    post 'books/create'
    post 'books/update'
    get 'books/list'
    get 'books/show'
    get 'books/edit'
    get 'books/delete'
    get 'books/update'
    get 'books/show_subjects'
  end
```

**view**

The below code gets the data from database and it displays the user. If user required he/she can  update the information, but when I pressed update button its showing the error.
I am using rails4 and eclipse IDE, and mysql2 gem and MySQL database. I am able to perform create,delete,list or show operation but I am unable to perform update operation. I am helpless and can give a suggestion to know the rails4 details with complete application

```
<h1>Edit Book Detail</h1>
<%=form_tag :action => 'update', :id => @book %>    
  <p>
    <label for="book_title">Title</label>:    
    <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="book_price">Price</label>:
    <%= text_field 'book', 'price' %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="book_subject">Subject</label>:        
    <%= collection_select(:book, :subject_id, enter code here @subjects, :id, :name) %>      
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="book_description">Description</label><br/>
    <%= text_area 'book', 'description' %>
  </p>

  # the below line is to update the content in the database          
  <%= submit_tag "Save changes" %>
  <%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
def update
        #below is the line I am getting the error....
        @book = Book.find(book1_params)

        if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
          redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @book
        else
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
          render :action => 'edit'
        end
      end
```

to

```
def update
  #below is the line I am getting the error....
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])

  if @book.update_attributes(book_params)
    redirect_to @book
  else
    @subjects = Subject.all
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```